# Getting rid of the .svn files in all directories

Tags: svn, version-control

Is there any way with subversion or any other VCS that i can keep the checked out files in the .svn directory in a different place then the directory where they "belong". For example having some toplevel /work/my-source-tree and a /work/my-source-tree-svn directory?

I know why the files are duplicated in .svn directories (fast detection of changed files at checkin and easy tool support). But i often want to do a backup of the files for example on an USB stick and transfering the double number of files is a showstopper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[svk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVK) is a layer on top of subversion that adds a few additional features. One key feature is that metadata is kept in $HOME/.svk/ instead of within each working copy. This separates the two and would make your backups easier and working copies smaller.

Plus, it also provides some distributed version control features, like git and others - but still using svn as the backend.  Might be worth a try.

Comment: SVK was discontinued. Use svn export.

Answer (score 11):

Use `svn export` to copy the files to a clean directory (ie, your USB stick). It will not copy the `.svn` directories. This also works for working copies:

```
svn export <path-to-working-copy> <destination-directory>
```

Answer (score 9):

With CVS, SVN and other version control systems, you can do an export. This allows you to get a copy of the code without the .svn or other hidden directories.

[SVN Export documentation](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html)

Comment: Well but what if want to take my project files to home to finish something before i check in?

Sorry export is not the answer i wanted to hear.

Comment: In that case, svk is likely what you want :p

Answer (score 2):

You could backup to your USB stick using rsync, and use the --cvs-exclude option. Depending on your version, this may not work for subversion files, so try --exclude='.svn/*'

Answer (score 1):

```
cd svn-local-dir
find . -name .svn | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: You can omit piping to `xargs` if you use the `-exec` options, i.e. `find . -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this is no longer an issue in Subversion 1.7.

> Instead of a .svn directory in every directory in the working copy, Subversion 1.7 working copies have just one .svn directory—in the root of the working copy. ([Subversion 1.7 Release Notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html))